# Ошибка компиляции React JS - Node Sass ver 6.0.1

Tags: reactjs, node-sass

Ребята, как можно решить эту проблему:

./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/index.scss)
Node Sass version 6.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0.

P.S. Редактор VSC

Answer (score 0):

Нашел коммент один на Github, вроде как пакет node-sass устарел и нужно пользоваться другим пакетом - sass

npm uninstall node-sass
npm i sass

После этого начал компилировать без ошибок.

Но возможен и другой ответ. Нашел пока такой.